# Date between intervals dynamic

Tags: postgresql, query

I have a table with all employee licenses and two dates in relation to a period of 2 years. I have to verify if have someone period sum of 30 days of license in one range 12 months

For example: data of range refer the 2 years between January of 2017 and January of 2019, we have of into January of 2017 and December of 2018 have 29 days of license not interest me, but the range between February of 2017 and January of 2018 has 33 days of the license and this interest me.

How do I create a query in Postgres to solve my problem?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to the site. If I understand correctly you have a start date for a license and an end date for a license and you want to know if someone had a license for 30 days? Do these days need to be consecutive or would 2 periods of 15 days qualify too? Can you add your table definitions and sample data to the question? Thanks

Comment: Hey Junior, it is a bit hard to understand what you are asking. Take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example for database-related questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and try to add some more information to your question. Thanks!